# Segmentation fault while using FFTW split arrays

Tags: c, split, fftw

I wanted to use FFTW split data and see its performance. So, I wrote this simple program basing on some examples that I've found on the internet.

The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "defines.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <fftw3.h>

int main(void)
{ 
  double *Xre, *Xim, *Yre, *Yim;
  int N = 4096;
  int i =0, j=0;
  fftw_plan Plan;
  fftw_iodim Dim;

  Xre =  fftw_malloc(sizeof(double) * N);
  Xim =  fftw_malloc(sizeof(double) * N);
  Yre =  fftw_malloc(sizeof(double) * N);
  Yim =  fftw_malloc(sizeof(double) * N);

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    Xre[i] = input_data[2*i];
    Xim[i] = input_data[2*i+1];
  }
  if(!(Plan = fftw_plan_guru_split_dft(1, &Dim, 0, NULL,Xre, Xim, Yre, Yim, FFTW_ESTIMATE)))
    printf("FFTW3 failed to create plan.");

  fftw_execute_split_dft(Plan, Xre, Xim, Yre, Yim);

  printf("RESULTS:\n\n");
  for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
  {
    printf("RE: %f,\tIM: %f \n", Yre[j], Yim[j]);
  }
  fftw_destroy_plan(Plan);
  fftw_free(Xre);
  fftw_free(Xim);
  fftw_free(Yre);
  fftw_free(Yim);
  return 0;
}
```

where Xre and Xim refer to the inputs both reals and imaginaries, and Yre, Yim is for the results. The `input_data` si declared in the `defines.h` file like so:

```
float input_data[8192] ={
-7.418860e-02,  1.188460e-03 ,  -1.612460e-02 ,  -7.506560e-02,
 7.372410e-02, -3.039230e-02 ,   4.457970e-02 ,   6.862750e-02,
-6.164490e-02,  5.634830e-02 ,  -6.556000e-02 ,  -5.147360e-02,
...          , ...           ,  ...           ,  ...           }
```

I did some debugging and it seems that the segmentation fault occurs in the execution line `fftw_execute_split_dft(Plan, Xre, Xim, Yre, Yim)`. I've read this post [fftw split example crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099349/fftw-split-example-crashes). But, I still don't get the reason behind this error.

Comment: where is `input_data` defined?

Comment: also shouldn't `fftw_iodim Dim` be initialized? because fftw lib cannot know the size of your arrays by just passing the pointers.

Comment: it's defined in the `defines.h` file I will edit my post to show it.

Comment: regarding: `if(!(Plan = fftw_plan_guru_split_dft(1, &Dim, 0, NULL,Xre, Xim, Yre, Yim, FFTW_ESTIMATE)))
    printf("FFTW3 failed to create plan.");` 1) when creating the 'plan' fails, the error message should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`. 2) after this failure, do not EVER try to use 'plan' instead, free all the memory allocations then exit the program.  I.E. `perror( "FFTW3 failed" ); fftw_free(Xre);
  fftw_free(Xim);
  fftw_free(Yre);
  fftw_free(Yim); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`  note: `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are from `stdlib.h`

Comment: after each line like: `Xre =  fftw_malloc(sizeof(double) * N);`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the `defines.h` entry `fftw_iodim Dim[] will have to contain 2*4096 entries.  Does it actually contain those 8k entries?

Comment: the posted code is missing `#include <stdio.h>` for `printf()`

Comment: the variable `N` should be declared as `size_t` not `int` to avoid an implicit conversion in the call to `fftw_malloc()`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding (the compiler does not care) 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the documentation:

```
fftw_plan fftw_plan_guru_split_dft(
     int rank, const fftw_iodim *dims,
     int howmany_rank, const fftw_iodim *howmany_dims,
     double *ri, double *ii, double *ro, double *io,
     unsigned flags);
```

You see that `dims` is passed as a *constant* pointer. So it requires to be initialized with the actual dimension of your arrays (and the library cannot compute the size from an array by just passing the pointer)

the structure is as follows:

```
typedef struct {
     int n;
     int is;
     int os;
} fftw_iodim;
```

> Here, n is the size of the dimension, and is and os are the strides of that dimension for the input and output arrays. (The stride is the separation of consecutive elements along this dimension.)

So your plan is improperly initialized with random array sizes. I would initialize as follows *before* creating the plan:

```
Dim.n = N;
Dim.is = 1;
Dim.os = 1;
```